# Vim　同じウィンドウで現在編集中のシェルスクリプトをデバッグする方法

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim, wsl

---

**環境**
Windows10 pro
WSL Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Vim 8.1

---

**やりたいこと**
Vimで現在編集中のシェルスクリプトをデバッグするような方法があれば知りたいです。

例として、私は通常以下の方法で自分の作成した、スクリプトの動作を確認しています。

ペイン「１」では下記図のようにteratail.shを編集中とします。
ペイン「２」は自分が作ったスクリプトを確認するためのものです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
ただ、これだと試すのにペインを移動しなければならないので、
少し手間に思います。

そのため理想としては...
1．編集ウィンドウで(デバッグ)コマンド実行
2．ウィンドウが分割される。
3．分割されたウィンドウで編集中のシェルファイルが実行される

という流れでできないのか？と考えています。

コマンド的に言えば、Terminalコマンドを実行するとVimの画面が分割されますが、
そこに、編集中のファイルを渡してあげて、実行させるようなことがしたいのです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

やり方を知っている方
もし、方法があれば教えて欲しいと思います。
私の考え方が違う場合も教えて頂ければ幸いです。

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/273903

Answer (score 1):

`:terminal` は引数で実行するコマンドを指定できます。無指定の場合は `$SHELL` が使われるので、通常はシェルが立ち上がります。
つまり以下のようなコマンドを実行すれば、現在のバッファを `bash` に渡して実行できます。`%` は現在バッファの名前に置き換えられて実行されます。

```
:terminal bash %
```